# Is there any good quality make-up brand which is 100% vegan?

Tags: veganism, cosmetics

I’ve just become vegan and I’m noticing things I’ve never noticed before. I was going to buy some make-up stuff as previously planned and after a bit of research, I realised they are probably not vegan (some are labelled "cruelty free" but I don't think that is enough).

One of my friends told me that if I want to know which product of each company is vegan I should send an email and ask for a list, which seems too much effort.

After I searched a lot, it seems to me that some make-up brands even lie about being vegan.

So, are there any make up and skin care brands which are 100% vegan?

Answer (score 3):

A good drugstore makeup brand would be elf cosmetics - I love their affordable brushes and highlighter! [Milk Makeup](https://www.milkmakeup.com/), [Inika](https://www.inikaorganic.com/), Kat Von D (if you're okay with her) and [Everyday Minerals](https://www.everydayminerals.com/store/) are great if you can spend more. KVD's eyeliner is a holy grail to many.

I've heard great things about [Sukin](https://sukinnaturals.com/) for their skincare products. Their products are environmentally sustainable, affordable and natural. I have personally used their body wash, shampoo and facial wash a few years back and they all smelt the same (not a bad thing!) and were suitable for my sensitive skin.

But here's a [link](https://ethicalelephant.com/vegan-makeup-skincare-brands/) to a list of 100% vegan makeup and skincare brands from ethical elephant!

Answer (score 2):

There is UK-based [PHB ethical beauty](https://www.phbethicalbeauty.co.uk/) which has large ranges of skincare and make up products. I have bought skincare products (moisturisers, hand creams, soaps) from them and found them to be of good quality.

Here's some information from their [About Us page](https://www.phbethicalbeauty.co.uk/about-phb)

> PHB Ethical Beauty is a pioneering British family business with a revolutionary range of award winning ethical beauty products. We're home to the world's largest range of Natural, Vegan, Cruelty Free & Alcohol Free (Halal Certified) beauty products. Our skin, hair & body care products are handmade in the UK and we DO NOT test on animals. We are also palm oil free!
>
> Our range includes Skin, Hair & Body care, Organic & Mineral Cosmetics and Male Grooming Products. Our products are so pure they make great Natural Remedies for Sensitive Skin and conditions such as Eczema, Psoriasis & Acne!
>
> PHB Ethical Beauty is the creation of 3 caring and passionate entrepreneurs who believe the cosmetics industry needs BIG CHANGE and that 100% Plant Powered & Compassionate beauty products will improve your skin, your health and your well-being.

I believe there are numerous vegan cosmetics companies but I am not aware of any as established or as comprehensive in their offer than PHB. Their skin shade range is better than most too.